# How to retrieve text of entry cell of custom cell in a list view in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new with Xamarin.Forms, I had created a list having Custom cell with 4 labels & 1 entry. I manage to display label & Entry. But I want to use the text from Entry cell. How to do it? My UI is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Daccx.png)

Below is code Model

```
public class DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int _id{ get; set;}
    public string DSO_CD{ get; set;}
    public string Beat_id{ get; set;}
    public string Retailer_cd{ get; set;}
    public string Retailer_nm{ get; set;}
    public string email{ get; set;}
    public string mobile{ get; set;}
    public DateTime birth_dt{ get; set;}
    public DateTime Anniversary_dt{ get; set;}
    public DateTime Lst_sync_dt{ get; set;}

}
```

Below is Page

```
public class RetailerListPage : ContentPage
{
    public RetailerListPage()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        Title = "Retailer List";

        CreateNewDB database = new CreateNewDB();
        database.saveDSOReatilMap(retailerlst);

        // Fetch data from LOCAL TABLE DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping
        List<DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping> RetailerList = database.GetDSOReatilMap("Select * from DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping ").ToList();

        ListView listview = new ListView();
        listview.RowHeight = 100;
        listview.ItemsSource = RetailerList;
        listview.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));  

        this.Content = listview;
    }

public class CustomCell : ViewCell
    {
        public CustomCell()
        {
    //Please Condider 4 labes & 1 Entry cell is created though below code have 1 label & 1 entry

            AbsoluteLayout cellView = new AbsoluteLayout();
            var retailernameLabel = new Label();
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(retailernameLabel, new Rectangle(5, 12 , AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize,AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
            retailernameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Retailer_nm"));
            retailernameLabel.FontSize = 18;
            retailernameLabel.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#434343");
            cellView.Children.Add(retailernameLabel);

    //Remaining 3 labels goes here

            var txtAmt = new Entry();
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(txtAmt, new Rectangle(5, 32, 500, 60));
            txtAmt.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding("inputAmt"));
            txtAmt.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
            txtAmt.TextColor = Color.Black;
            cellView.Children.Add(txtAmt);

            this.View = cellView;

            View = new StackLayout()
            {
                BackgroundColor = rowcolor,
                Children = { cellView }
            };

        }
    }

}
```

Also please specify what are the mistakes in above code and what is the proper way to bind data.

CODE CHANGES ARE AS FOLLOWS

```
public class RetailerListPage : ContentPage
{
    public RetailerListPage()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        Title = "Retailer List";

        BindingContext = new RetailerListPageViewModel();

        ListView listview = new ListView();
        listview.RowHeight = 100;

        listview.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));

        listview.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "RetailerList");

        Content = listview;
    }

    public class CustomCell : ViewCell
    {
        public CustomCell()
        {
           #region Code that Customizes Cell

            AbsoluteLayout cellView = new AbsoluteLayout();
            var retailernameLabel = new Label();
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(retailernameLabel, new Rectangle(5, 12, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
            retailernameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Retailer_nm"));
            retailernameLabel.FontSize = 18;
            retailernameLabel.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#434343");
            cellView.Children.Add(retailernameLabel);

            var txtAmt = new Entry();
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(txtAmt, new Rectangle(5, 32, 500, 60));
            txtAmt.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding("InputAmt"));
            txtAmt.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
            txtAmt.TextColor = Color.Black;
            cellView.Children.Add(txtAmt);

            this.View = cellView;

            View = new StackLayout()
            {
              Children = { cellView }
            };
            #endregion
        }
    }

}
```

Added a new property for inputAmt into Model is as follows

```
public class DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string _inputAmt;  //NEWLY ADDED
    public int _id;
    public string _DSO_CD;
    public string _Beat_id;
    public string _Retailer_cd;
    public string _Retailer_nm;
    public string _email;
    public string _mobile;
    public DateTime _birth_dt;
    public DateTime _Anniversary_dt;
    public DateTime _Lst_sync_dt;
    public string InputAmt
    {
        get
        {
            return _inputAmt;
        }

        set
        {
            _inputAmt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("inputAmt");
        }
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }

        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public string DSO_CD
    {
        get
        {
            return _DSO_CD;
        }

        set
        {
            _DSO_CD = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DSO_CD");
        }
    }

    public string Beat_id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Beat_id;
        }

        set
        {
            _Beat_id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Beat_id");
        }
    }

    public string Retailer_cd
    {
        get
        {
            return _Retailer_cd;
        }

        set
        {
            _Retailer_cd = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Retailer_cd");
        }
    }

    public string Retailer_nm
    {
        get
        {
            return _Retailer_nm;
        }

        set
        {
            _Retailer_nm = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Retailer_nm");
        }
    }

    public string email
    {
        get
        {
            return _email;
        }

        set
        {
            _email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("email");
        }
    }

    public string mobile
    {
        get
        {
            return _mobile;
        }

        set
        {
            _mobile = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("mobile");
        }
    }

    public DateTime birth_dt
    {
        get
        {
            return _birth_dt;
        }

        set
        {
            _birth_dt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("birth_dt");
        }
    }

    public DateTime Anniversary_dt
    {
        get
        {
            return _Anniversary_dt;
        }

        set
        {
            _Anniversary_dt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Anniversary_dt");
        }
    }

    public DateTime Lst_sync_dt
    {
        get
        {
            return _Lst_sync_dt;
        }

        set
        {
            _Lst_sync_dt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Lst_sync_dt");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And ViewModel is as follows

```
 public class RetailerListPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping> retailerList;

    public RetailerListPageViewModel()
    {
        #region Here data inserted for test purpose 
        //DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping retailerlst = new DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping
        //{
        //    InputAmt = "200",
        //    _id = 1,
        //    DSO_CD = "123",
        //    Beat_id = "111",
        //    Retailer_nm = "XYZ RETAILER",
        //    email = "ZYZ@ABCD.com",
        //    mobile = "1234567890",
        //    birth_dt = DateTime.Now,
        //    Anniversary_dt = DateTime.Now,
        //    Lst_sync_dt = DateTime.Now
        //};

        //DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping retailerlst1 = new DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping
        //{
        //    InputAmt = "200",
        //    _id = 1,
        //    DSO_CD = "123",
        //    Beat_id = "111",
        //    Retailer_cd = "R123",
        //    Retailer_nm = "XYZ RETAILER",
        //    email = "ZYZ@ABCD.com",
        //    mobile = "1234567890",
        //    birth_dt = DateTime.Now,
        //    Anniversary_dt = DateTime.Now,
        //    Lst_sync_dt = DateTime.Now
        //};
        #endregion

        CreateNewDB database = new CreateNewDB();
        //database.saveDSOReatilMap(retailerList);  
        //database.saveDSOReatilMap(retailerlst1);

       RetailerList = database.GetDSOReatilMap("Select * from DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping ").ToList();
    }

        public List<DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping> RetailerList
    {
        get { return retailerList; }

        set
        {
            retailerList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RetailerList");
        }
    }

    public Command btnSave
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() => {
                // Code to save List 

            });
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

following `CreateNewDB` is class to access database

```
public class CreateNewDB
{
    static object locker = new object ();
    SQLiteConnection database;

    public CreateNewDB ()
    {

        database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite> ().GetConnection ();

        database.DropTable<DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping> ();
        database.CreateTable<DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping> ();
    }


    //DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping
    public IEnumerable<DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping> GetDSOReatilMap(string query)
    {
        lock (locker) {
            return database.Query<DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping> (query);
        }
    }

    public string saveDSOReatilMap(DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping item)
    {
        lock (locker) {
            database.Insert(item);
            return item.Retailer_cd;
        }
    }
//UPDATE DB  
public string UpdateDSOReatilMap(DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping item)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            database.Update(item);
            return item.Retailer_cd;
        }
    }
    public int DeleteDSOReatilMap(string empcd)
    {
        lock (locker) {
            return database.Delete<DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping> (empcd);
        }
    }


}
```

My Problems are :

1. Still Not able to populate list
2. I need to add NEXT BUTTON (As present in attached image) on `RetailerListPage` so that details can be used on Next Page.
3. Unable to the UPDATED details in Database i.e.(Amount)

Please guide.

Comment: show us code relevant to the question and what you actually tried so far

Comment: @ArkadiuszK Please check the updates & guide

Comment: Did you include modification to `RetailerListPageViewModel`, that one regarding `RetailerList` property? Your other problems apart from populating list are not related  to the question you asked. I think you have to create separate questions for them.

Comment: You didn't include code for `RetailerListPageViewModel`. That's why I am asking.

Comment: I apologize. I pasted same code Model in ViewModel also. But now I made corrections into the Post.

Comment: @Arkadiusz K Thank you very much, Its working now there are some other issues, I resolved them. Can you please guide how to save the updated list into database using the method `saveDSOReatilMap` in class `CreateNewDB`

Comment: You need to use `Update` metod rather than `Insert` to update item in database after making changes on the UI

Comment: @ArkadiuszK I really thanks for sharing Knowledge. I had now Added Method `UpdateDSOReatilMap`. Is it correct.?? If yes then How to Update List. Please suggest.

Comment: How do you plan to expose update functionality on UI? In `RetailerListPageViewModel` or somehow different?

Comment: In `RetailerListPageViewModel` on button click from UI. i.e. Button on `RetailerListPage ` will invoke a method to update/save details into DB.

Comment: So, you have list with items in `RetailerListPageViewwModel`, get those which were modified, iterate over it and call `Update` for every modified item.

Comment: at the beginning in your SaveCommand you can iterate over all items and just invoke update on every item. Next, you can try to figure out how to mark those items which where modified and update only them

Answer (score 2):

Widely used pattern in `Xamarin.Forms` is **MVVM** pattern (which stands for Model View ViewModel). It is used for separating specific UI code from business logic code. Following that pattern you create ViewModel class, which prepare data for View and allows to connect View with Model (hence the name). Important piece, which allows actually binding ViewModel to View is `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. ViewModel should implement this interface to notify view about changes which happened in ViewModel. Then, when something happen in ViewModel, it should raise `OnPropertyChanged` method which actually send *notification* to view. Other important part is that view must know to which ViewModel subscribe for notifications. For that purpose we use `BindingContext` property. Refer to following code and I think it should be clear.

In your case we can create `RetailerListPageViewModel` for `RetailerListPage`:

```csharp
public class RetailerListPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping> retailerList;

    public RetailerListPageViewModel()
    {
        CreateNewDB database = new CreateNewDB();
        database.saveDSOReatilMap(retailerlst);

        // Fetch data from LOCAL TABLE DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping
        RetailerList = database
                               .GetDSOReatilMap("Select * from DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping ")
                               .ToList();
    }


    public List<DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping> RetailerList
    {
        get { return retailerList; }
        set 
        { 
            retailerList = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("RetailerList");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can modify `RetailerListPage` to use ViewModel we have created (by using `BindingContext` property):

```csharp
public class RetailerListPage : ContentPage
{
    public RetailerListPage()
    {
       BackgroundColor = Color.White;
       Title = "Retailer List";

       BindingContext = new RetailerListPageViewModel();

       ListView listview = new ListView();
       listview.RowHeight = 100;
       listview.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));

       listview.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "RetailerList");  

       this.Content = listview;
    }
}
```

When you are binding `ListView` to some collection of data, then every `CustomCell` gets as a `BindingContext` assigned an item from that collection. You can think that it becomes now the ViewModel for `CustomCell`. That's actually explanation why your code for displaying labels works. So, you are trying bind `Entry.Text` to `inputAmt` property but property named `inputAmt` does not exist in `DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping` class. Thus you need to create ViewModel with that property and other properties you want to display:

```csharp
public class BeatRetailerItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _inputAmt;  
    private string retailerNm;

    public string inputAmt
    {
        get { return _inputAmt; }
        set 
        { 
            _inputAmt= value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("inputAmt");
        }
    }

    public string Retailer_nm 
    { 
        get { return retailerNm; }
        set 
        { 
            retailerNm = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Retailer_nm");
        }
    }

    //and other properties that you need to display
    //and INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}
```

Ok, but we don't get out of the woods yet. Now we must amend `RetailerListPageViewModel` accordignly to use new ViewModel (I omit `INotifyPropertyChanged` code because you can see it in above example):

```csharp
public class RetailerListPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<BeatRetailerItemViewModel> retailerList;

    public RetailerListPageViewModel()
    {
        CreateNewDB database = new CreateNewDB();
        database.saveDSOReatilMap(retailerlst);

        // Fetch data from LOCAL TABLE DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping
        RetailerList = database
                               .GetDSOReatilMap("Select * from DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping ")
                               .Select(x => new BeatRetailerItemViewModel { Retailer_nm = x.Retailer_nm })
                               .ToList();
    }

    public List<BeatRetailerItemViewModel> RetailerList
    {
        get { return retailerList; }
        set 
        { 
            retailerList = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("RetailerList");
        }
    }

    //INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}
```

I hope you see pattern there :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer.

Comment: I forgot to add Property `inputAmt ` in class `DSO_beat_Retailer_mapping` but now I Added `inputAmt`. Hence due to this no need to create `BeatRetailerItemViewModel` right?? But now list doesn't show any data  :(

Comment: Yes, you are right. Despite of that, I made a mistake in `RetailerListPageViewModel` because collection wasn't assigned to `RetailerList` property. I have fixed code example.